# Debugging Hadoop remotely in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I am new in Hadoop world. I have a remote Hadoop Cluster. I want to coding in java at home with Eclipse and run the codes in the Hadoop Cluster.

I found the some similar topics with different answers, so I don't know which one is suitable. I made a conclusion, it should be two step:

1. configue in eclipse: Debug Configurations -> Remote Java Application -> New -> input the "Host" and "Port"
2. Call the Hadoop administrater, he should do the following for me:

   - export HADOOP_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5000"
   - restart hadoop

Is it so easy? Or there are some additional steps I need to do?

Comment: @JFPicard I called the the Company which hosts Hadoop Cluster to do that for me, today. At moment, I didn't get any feedback, whether they will do that for me. On the other side, I asked some guys in my company, they told me, they guess it won't work, because Hadoop is a distributed system.

Comment: The way remote debugging works in eclipse is by eclipse debugger connecting to the debug port of JVM instance started with debug parameters (using JPWD parameters).
So technically you would need to have that many remote debugger instances running from within single eclipse instance which I don't think is likely possible. Atleast I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of job you would like to run (MapReduce or HDFS). 
You could try adding the fully-qualified path to the Hadoop cluster's configuration to the classpath of your application. The `core-default-site.xml` must come first, followed by the `core-site.xml`, and then any other additional configurations you need. See the Hadoop Javadoc for more specific details : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html . There is also the option of running the applications remotely via SSH.